# HTML: Paragraphs after table, appearing to right of table

Tags: html, alignment

We are designing an application that will send e-mail to managers reminding them that they have to do certain approvals.  The e-mail is in HTML form, and contains a table.  We don't understand what we're doing wrong to cause the last paragraph to appear to the right of the table instead of under it.

A sample is below.  The tool "tidy," on which I rely for things like this, has no tips this time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org"
name="generator">
<meta content='text/html; charset=us-ascii' http-equiv=
"Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
   body {font-family: Calibri;   }
   caption {font-family: Calibri;color: 'black'; font-size: '125%;  }
   table.main tr { };
   table.main td.bottomcaption {text-align: 'center'; vertical-align: 'middle'; font-family: 'Calibri'; color: 'black'; font-color: 'black'; font-size: '125%';   }
   table.main th {vertical-align: 'bottom'; color: blue; background-color: lightyellow;   }
</style>
<title>Payable Time awaiting approval</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, <strong>Daffy Duck</strong>:</p>
<p>According to our records, the following Payable Time is awaiting
approval. Items shown below must be approved in order for
compensation to take place.<br></p>
<p>For questions, please contact <a href=
"MAILTO:SUPPORT@OUR_ORG.COM">Support</a></p>
<table align="left" border="1" class='main' summary="Pending details">
<caption ><strong>Awaiting approval by your reporting
structure</strong></caption>
<tr>
<th align="left">&nbsp;<br>
Name</th>
<th align="center">&nbsp;<br>
ID</th>
<th align="center">Work<br>
Date</th>
<th align="center">&nbsp;<br>
Type</th>
<th align="center">&nbsp;<br>
Hours</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">Reporting to Mickey M Mouse (MMM)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Daisy</td>
<td align="left">D_DUCK</td>
<td align="center">04/29/2013</td>
<td align="left">REG</td>
<td align="right">8.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Daisy</td>
<td align="left">D_DUCK</td>
<td align="center">05/01/2013</td>
<td align="left">REG</td>
<td align="right">8.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Daisy</td>
<td align="left">D_DUCK</td>
<td align="center">05/02/2013</td>
<td align="left">OT</td>
<td align="right">7.50</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;<br></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>This message comes from The Support Team</p>
</body>
</html>
```

We would very much like for the text "This message comes from..." to appear below the table, but instead it appears to the right of the table, aligned with the table's top.  This is true for IE7, IE8 and Firefox 12.

I'd appreciate any suggestions to help this situation.

Regards,
Dennis

Comment: remove the align="left" to the table

Comment: Yep, @Francis is correct. Also your CSS is missing a quote mark after the `125%` in the `caption` rule and there is a semi-colon after `table.main tr` that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use similar markup to this: http://jsfiddle.net/7fAy9/2/

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">This is the text you want under the table</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

or,
you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NNrnc/

```
<table border="1">
  <caption align="bottom">My savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but please notice the `caption` align is deprecated in HTML5,
the correct way to do it in HTML5 would be:

```
<table border="1">
  <caption style="caption-side:bottom">My savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, just realized you do not try to add text closely related to the table.

Comment: Thanks for this; it works a treat.  Thanks also for pointing out about the deprecated CAPTION attribute.

Comment: The first approach doesn't work if you have more than one table row. Its footer will get rendered at the very bottom of the table. Seems to be a bug in Chrome's rendering engine.

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the `align="left"` to your table.

see the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rhyDe/

Tested on IE10, FF24, Chrome 30

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question. He wants the text below the table.

Answer (score 1):

i changed mine to `<table align="center ">` (center+tab) and that knocked my paragraph down exactly where it should be.

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix. Add this to the last sentence:

```
<p style="float:left;">This message comes from the support team.</p>
```